# Adding input value from a form to an ul

Tags: javascript

I have a user input under a form, and I am trying to get the input to be added as a li under an ul. This is my code so far:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#lagre");
var reminderList = document.querySelector("#reminderList");
var input = document.forms.reminderForm.reminder;

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //console.log(input.value); 
});
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="reminderContainer">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Min huskeliste</h1>
      <ul id="reminderList">

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <form action="#" name="reminderForm">
        <div class="reminderInput">
          <label for="reminder">Jeg må huske...</label>
          <input autofocus type="text" name="reminder">
        </div>

        <input id="lagre" type="submit" name="submit" value="Lagre">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var li = document.createElement("li"); // create an li
  li.textContent = input.value;          // set its text content to input's value
  reminderList.appendChild(li);          // add it to the ul
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#lagre");
var reminderList = document.querySelector("#reminderList");
var input = document.forms.reminderForm.reminder;

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var li = document.createElement("li"); // create an li
  li.textContent = input.value; // set its text content to input's value
  reminderList.appendChild(li); // add it to the ul
});
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="reminderContainer">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Min huskeliste</h1>
      <ul id="reminderList">

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <form action="#" name="reminderForm">
        <div class="reminderInput">
          <label for="reminder">Jeg må huske...</label>
          <input autofocus type="text" name="reminder">
        </div>

        <input id="lagre" type="submit" name="submit" value="Lagre">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/tLx48h5L/
It pass the value to a function and create options inside the ul with the value of the input.

```
function createLis(option){
    var template = "<option>"+option+"</option>";
    var content = document.querySelector("#reminderList").innerHTML;
    document.querySelector("#reminderList").innerHTML = content + template;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can select your reminder input element:

```
var reminderValue = document.querySelector("#reminder");
```

And add it's value to your li element

```
reminderList.innerHTML = reminderValue.value;
```

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#lagre");
var reminderList = document.querySelector("#reminderList");
var reminderValue = document.querySelector("#reminder");
var input = document.forms.reminderForm.reminder;

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 reminderList.innerHTML = reminderValue.value;

  //console.log(input.value); 
});
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="reminderContainer">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Min huskeliste</h1>
      <ul id="reminderList">

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <form action="#" name="reminderForm">
        <div class="reminderInput">
          <label for="reminder">Jeg må huske...</label>
          <input autofocus type="text" name="reminder" id="reminder">
        </div>

        <input id="lagre" type="submit" name="submit" value="Lagre">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4wfrkvxs/

Answer (score 0):

Check plz this solution.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#lagre");
var reminderList = document.querySelector("#reminderList");
var input = document.forms.reminderForm.reminder;

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = document.getElementById('reminder').value;

  document.getElementById('reminderList').appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="reminderContainer">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Min huskeliste</h1>
      <ul id="reminderList">

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <form action="#" name="reminderForm">
        <div class="reminderInput">
          <label for="reminder">Jeg må huske...</label>
          <input autofocus type="text" id="reminder" name="reminder">
        </div>

        <input id="lagre" type="submit" name="submit" value="Lagre">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```